# javascript regexp positive look behind to dynamicly replace/wrap text in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery/Javascript, I want to match text within multiple containers and wrap a link around the text while using the matched text in the URL.

### Input HTML:

```
<div id="sampleText">
The dog jumped over the fence id:12345-6789 and ran into another fence id:98765-4321.
</div>

<div>
The dog continued to jump over fence id:12345-6789 and again ran into another fence id:98765-4321.
</div>
```

### Output HTML:

```
<div>
The dog jumped over the fence id:<a href="123.45678.com.com?id=12345-6789">12345-6789</a> and ran into another fence id:<a href="123.45678.com?id=98765-4321">98765-4321</a>.
</div>

<div>
The dog continued to jump over fence id:<a href="123.45678.com.com?id=12345-6789">12345-6789</a> and again ran into another fence id:<a href="123.45678.com?id=98765-4321">98765-4321</a>.
</div>
```

Here is what I have so far (not working)...

```
$("div:contains('fence id:')").html(function(_,html){
     var rx = new RegExp('fence id:[0-9A-Z-]+','gi');
     return html.replace(rx, '<a href="123.45678.com?id='+$1+'">'+$1+'</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're super close!

First, you need to make sure that your regex is actually capturing the id text by using `()` to create a capturing group:

```
var rx = new RegExp('fence id:([0-9A-Z-]+)','gi');
```

Second, when referencing the capturing group using `$1` you actually want to just include it right in the replacement string, rather than treating it as a variable:

```
return html.replace(rx, '<a href="123.45678.com?id=$1">$1</a>');
```

```js
$("div:contains('fence id:')").html(function(_,html){
     var rx = new RegExp('fence id:([0-9A-Z-]+)','gi');
     return html.replace(rx, '<a href="123.45678.com?id=$1">$1</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleText">
The dog jumped over the fence id:12345-6789 and ran into another fence id:98765-4321.
</div>

<div>
The dog continued to jump over fence id:12345-6789 and again ran into another fence id:98765-4321.
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! Beating my head against the desk on this one. Thanks!